# Echarts, rotating titles

Tags: echarts

Does somebody know how to rotate axis titles?
An example is here: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-stack but about rotating legends nothing cannot found.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`nameRotate`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.nameRotate).

```js
yAxis: {
  //...,
  name: 'You Title',
  nameRotate: 90,
}
```